# UWP RichEditBox Text with Inline Rich Objects

Tags: facebook, winrt-xaml, uwp

I am working on a UWP app and I'm basically trying to do exactly what Facebook does with their app when composing a post.

Basically I want to be able to type text and At Mention someone in the RichEditBox. The person's name should be highlighted and when I tap on it I should be able to invoke a Command in my view model. Also once I hit send, I need to parse out what is text and what's a link to a person's account. I've played around a lot with the RichEditBox but can't quite figure this out.

Does anyone have any hints or ideas? I'm thinking I'll have to keep track of my object's position on every keystroke, just wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the RichTextBox.Document.Selection.Link property to store a custom link to your entity (ex: "mention://JohnDoe")

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextrange.link.aspx